# How to Verify Backup Archive in MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, query

I would like to know if there is any way to verify MySQL backup files. (Check if the file is valid or not for restore). Thanks!!

Comment: Please post questions in English here. There may or may not be other sites which allow questions in other languages, but not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to validate a backup file is to restore it. Anything else will be unreliable.